# How to wrap the row text in table?

Tags: lwuit

i have created the table by using TableModel and Table API in LWUIT. I did successfully , but While adding big text ( sentence like 'this is a sample program'), it won't wrap the text instead of displayed as text with dots ( Ex: this...). How to wrap the text in row?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405422/wrap-label-text-in-j2me

Comment: Thanks,...i tried this. but it cut only some words from the sentence ( like this is a sample program instead of i'm getting this is a sample),it didn't wrap the text.

Answer (score 0):

Override the Table's createCell method and instead of returning a Label from that method return a TextArea. Set it to editable false and invoke `setUIID("TableCell")` on it so it will look like a table cell.